# C++ type overloading issue

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes in a project, A, B and C. B is derived from A. And B can be constructed from C (it has a constructor B::B(C& c). If a method requires type B, I can use C instance instead.

Although C can be converted to B, I can not pass C directly as a parameter to functions requiring A.

```
void func(A a) {}
C c;
// calling func
func(c); // compile error
func(B(c)); // casting to B first; works.
```

Is it possible to have func(c) to compile? Due to some other factors, I cannot add constructor to construct A directly from C: A::A(C&) is not allowed.

Comment: You're not casting there, thats a copy.

Comment: Implement user defined conversion from C to B.

Comment: @tkausl - `B(c)` is a function-style cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker it does call the copy-constructor, doesn't it? https://ideone.com/QKxrcH

Comment: @tkausl - well, yes, in order to pass an `A` by value, the `A` object has to be copied. But `B(c)` doesn't do that; it's a **cast** that tells the compiler to convert `c` to an object of type `B`. The `A` subobject of that temporary `B` object gets copied, but that happens regardless of the origin of the argument.

Comment: @PeteBecker so how does it _cast_ it? In his example, `B` and `C` are two completely unrelated classes so there is neither a down- nor a up-cast which would make sense to the compiler and `B(...)` just looks like an ordinary constructor-call to me, in this example a copy-constructor-call (as he has one defined as `B::B(C& c)` even though it takes a non-const reference).

Comment: @tkausl - again: `B(c)` is a **function-style cast**. The compiler uses the `B`  constructor that takes an object of type `C&` to **convert** the `C` object to an object of type `B`. `B(C&)` is **not** a copy constructor (nor is `B(const C&)`). Some people call these converting constructors. If you're still confused about this, ask a question. Comments are not appropriate for this sort of discussion.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles in VS2012:

```
class A { };
class B : public A { };
class C
{
public:
    operator B() { return B(); }   // User defined conversion.
                                   // This is pseudo code just to satisfy the syntax.
};

void func(A a) { }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    C c;
    func(c);
    func(B(c));
}
```

This is close to your code. Some adjustments might be needed.